# VBO (views Bulk Operation) to send mails, mailings, ans SMSs?

Tags: drupal-views

CiviCRM 5.6.0

Is it possible to use VBO (views Bulk Operation) to send mails, mailings, ans SMSs ?

How ?

Comment: in a scenario where users were prohibited from accessing civicrm directly the only quick option we came up with was to make a webform, user adds the body of the mailing in one field, in other fields user explains who it should go to, then an admin constructs the mailing for them. this was

Comment: Thank you Pete ;  I think that I have been suggested a good solution in my other (alternate) post (civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27235/…) : use VBO to flag a custom field, and have a smart Group based upon this custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although CiviCRM entities are exposed to Drupal via CiviCRM Entity module, they are still not Drupal entities.

So in VBO even though you might think you can modify entity values to CiviCRM entities, it does not work very well at all.

Also in VBO even in Drupal you cannot send an email using this method. In VBO all you can do is modify entity values or execute a PHP script.

You would have to use a combination of VBO and Drupal Rules to send an email. And none of that would be recorded as a CiviCRM activity.

Not for me to ask, but using CiviCRM Scheduled reminders and inbuilt CiviMail would be a much easier option.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your attention ; I understand that VBO is not the solution. I have openned a new post to ask for other solutions based upon Views : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27235/how-to-use-views-to-send-a-mailing-to-a-selection-of-recipients

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBO by creating a custom action.  See [Views Bulk Operations development guide (Drupal 7)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067)

The CiviCooP [E-mail API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) and [SMS API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api) extensions might be useful.

Comment: Thank you Aidan ; but I am not a developper and I think that I have been suggested a good solution in my other (alternate) post (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27235/how-to-use-views-to-send-a-mailing-to-a-selection-of-recipients)

Comment: Glad you have a solution.  This one might help someone else!